# Restructuring the case-by-case analysis to be explicit and avoid duplicate sentences

Tags: formatting

I am working on my thesis (in computer science) and this is the paragraph I am struggling with. I am wondering is there a way to avoid duplication and yet have a case-by-case description?

Maybe if there is a way to say the same as above or combine two cases. Not sure.

> The following case-by-case description analyzes each scenario.
>
> - circular visit inside of circular visit: no fixed point loop is needed as it is left to parent visit to repeat evaluation and
>   naturally parent fixed-point loop will include child visit as well.
> - non-circular visit in circular visit: no fixed-point loop is needed and visit has to evaluate only once.
> - non-circular visit in non-circular visit: no fixed-point loop is needed and visit has to evaluate only once.
> - circular visit in non-circular visit: fixed-point loop is needed.

Comment: Welcome! (I'm chuckling—you're looking for a less recursive way of discussing recursion? Yes, there is a certain [Rumsfeldian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_are_known_knowns) quality, perhaps inherent in the subject matter.) Be aware, requests for general writing help and proofreading are not [on-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help). I think you have a clear concern—"duplication"—but could you perhaps edit to elaborate a little more on what part bothers you and what parameters you're forced to stay within?

Comment: Also, spoiler for my full answer: Is there any reason this has to be presented in bullet points? My inclination would be to move in the opposite direction from [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and use a bit more language—maybe introduce the scenarios first, then elaborate on their differences in full sentences.

Comment: @AndyBonner no reason it has to be a bullet point. Yes. I am looking for a way to avoid duplication.

Comment: Duplication is the core of parallel construction. When you repeat a construction that has been parsed already, the addressee doesn't have to parse it again and can get to the differences, which are always more significant than the similarities. Get rid of those not by deleting them but by repeating them, making them old information and foregrounding the differences.

Comment: @JohnLawler can you please be more specific? English is not my first language.

Comment: Looks like you have a 2x2 square of X within Y. That lends itself nicely to a Punnett Square. Your readers will mentally organize the material that way, it's best to meet them there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digesting technical material ahead of your readers is a blessing you bestow on them. Keeps them absorbing each juicy morsel of your research:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe:

*A child circular visit inside a parent circular visit does not need a fixed point loop; the parent visit's fixed-point loop controls the looping.*

***Does the Child Visit Need a Fixed-Point Loop?***

```
                         Parent Circular Visit     Parent Noncircular Visit

Child Circular Visit              no                     yes
    
Child Noncircular Visit           no                     no
```